# How to convert array of objects into array of arrays

Tags: javascript

The array of objects looks like this:

```
[
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000},
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000},
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000},
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000}
]
```

and the required JavaScript array is:

```
[
    [160000, 64], [160000, 64], [160000, 64], [160000, 64],
    [160000, 64], [160000, 64], [160000, 64], [160000, 64]
]
```

I want to convert JSON object data into JavaScipt and JSON data which I supply is given above and JavaScript array which I want is also defined. I want a JavaScript methode which solves this problem

Comment: [Have you tried anything](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) - this is a really trivial task.

Comment: [You have asked that question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030575/how-to-convert-json-object-into-into-javascript-format) and it was closed for a reason. Read the close reason and edit the question accordingly so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using this exact structure, you can do something like this. Where `inputData` is the first JSON structure, and `outputData` will be the data outputted.

```
var outputData = [];

for(var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
    var input = inputData[i];

    outputData.push([input.Earning, input.Number]);
}
```

Comment: Good, but I would suggest `outputData[i] = [...]` instead of using `.push()`, just to save a function call ;)

Comment: Meh, micro-optimizations, but good point. I just like it for the cleanliness per say.

Comment: I know, I know, I'm a nut like that XD But if I know the index number already I just like to make use of it.

Comment: @Kolink: how about `var outputData = new Array(inputData.length);` then?

Comment: @Kolink: but then you would have a single allocation

Comment: @Austin how to show these output array in alert message.please reply

Comment: I suggest using `console.log(outputData)` and viewing the output in the developer console, but if you insist on using `alert()` you can try `alert(JSON.stringify(outputData))`.

Comment: @Austin i use alert(JSON.stringify(outputData)) but output is not right.it show like this                                  [[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],

Comment: What's the output of `alert(JSON.stringify(inputData))`?

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(inputData))  give me result like this"[{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000},{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000},{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000},{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000},{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000},{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000},{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000},{\"Number\":64,\"Earning\":160000}]"

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array and construct a new array. Most javascript libraries have a `map` function where you only need to supply a mapping function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This Way (Works only in modern browsers):

```
var a = [
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000},
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000},
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000},
    {"Number":64,"Earning":160000},{"Number":64,"Earning":160000}
];

var b = a.map(function(i) {  return [i.Earning,i.Number];  });   // New Array
```

Comment: And where is the result? `forEach` does not modify the original array.

Comment: Really? It seems to modify the original array as well... when I checked in my console.

Comment: Somehow you must have checked it wrong ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Really sorry about the mistake. I did use map in console... which gave me the other result.

Comment: `.map` *returns* the new array though, so you have to assign the result to a variable.