# Vue.JS convert array of objects into array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

In vue my data looks like this:

```
data: {
    messages: []
  }
```

But the data returned from the api looks like this (array of objects)

```
messages: Array(1)
 0: Object
  message: "qwerqwer"
```

How do I convert a array of objects into an array of arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array of objects into array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031210/how-to-convert-array-of-objects-into-array-of-arrays)

Comment: Please, do some research before asking a question on Stack Overflow. See [ask]. I copied and pasted your title into the search bar and found the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you want it to do, but you should try to understand and not just blind copy it:

```
messages = messages.map(
    function(message){
        return message.message;
    }
);
```

Read about [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)