# Javascript convert a JSON string to an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to convert a JSON string with the following data :

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "info": "7811 N. Octavia",
        "longitude": -87.8086439,
        "latitude": 42.0229656
    }, {
        "info": "PO Box 271743",
        "longitude": -73.087749,
        "latitude": 41.6032207
    }, {
        "info": "P.O. Box 269",
        "longitude": -86.7818523,
        "latitude": 34.0667074
    }]
}
```

to the following structure:

```
var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];
```

Is there any way to achieve this using javascript?

Comment: What's the relation between the two?

Comment: yes, using Object.values and Array#map

Comment: you cannot as there is no relation in between. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array of objects into array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031210/how-to-convert-array-of-objects-into-array-of-arrays)

Comment: check my answer it might help you bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
    "locations": [{
        "info": "7811 N. Octavia",
        "longitude": -87.8086439,
        "latitude": 42.0229656
    }, {
        "info": "PO Box 271743",
        "longitude": -73.087749,
        "latitude": 41.6032207
    }, {
        "info": "P.O. Box 269",
        "longitude": -86.7818523,
        "latitude": 34.0667074
    }]
};

locations = obj.locations.map(({info, longitude, latitude}) => [info, longitude, latitude]);

console.log(locations);
```

You can just map over the array and return the elements in the form you want to create a new array

Answer (score 5):

You could get the values, as long as they have the right order.

```js
var object = { locations: [{ info: "7811 N. Octavia", longitude: -87.8086439, latitude: 42.0229656 }, { info: "PO Box 271743", longitude: -73.087749, latitude: 41.6032207 }, { info: "P.O. Box 269", longitude: -86.7818523, latitude: 34.0667074 }] },
    locations = object.locations.map(Object.values);

console.log(locations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Could you explain how works .map(Object.values) if "values" is a method of Object. I'm lost in that part.

Comment: [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)` takes a callback. [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) works directly and has only one parameter. Without the calling parentheses, you could hand over this method like any other callback.

Comment: Thanks, very smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `forEach()` on `locations` array:

```js
var obj = {"locations":[{"info":"7811 N. Octavia","longitude":-87.8086439,"latitude":42.0229656},{"info":"PO Box 271743","longitude":-73.087749,"latitude":41.6032207},{"info":"P.O. Box 269","longitude":-86.7818523,"latitude":34.0667074}]};

var res = [];
obj.locations.forEach(function(location){
  var innerArr = [];
  innerArr.push(location.info);
  innerArr.push(location.longitude);
  innerArr.push(location.latitude);
  res.push(innerArr);
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
//Parsing JSON string to json object
var dataObj = JSON.parse('{"locations":[{"info":"7811 N. Octavia","longitude":-87.8086439,"latitude":42.0229656},{"info":"PO Box 271743","longitude":-73.087749,"latitude":41.6032207},{"info":"P.O. Box 269","longitude":-86.7818523,"latitude":34.0667074}]}')

//Using map to iterate over dataObj.locations and break the object into array based on keys
var locations = dataObj.locations.map(x => [x.info, x.longitude, x.latitude])

console.log(locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code accept any object structure

```
let obj = {
  "locations": [{
      "info": "7811 N. Octavia",
      "longitude": -87.8086439,
      "latitude": 42.0229656
  }, {
      "info": "PO Box 271743",
      "longitude": -73.087749,
      "latitude": 41.6032207
  }, {
      "info": "P.O. Box 269",
      "longitude": -86.7818523,
      "latitude": 34.0667074
  }]
}

let arr = obj.locations.map(value => {
  let _arr = [];
  for (let key of Object.keys(value)) {
    _arr.push(value[key]);
  }
  return _arr
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

use reduce function to ittrate and put it value into a array and get the value.check the below code

```js
let v ={
    "locations": [{
        "info": "7811 N. Octavia",
        "longitude": -87.8086439,
        "latitude": 42.0229656
    }, {
        "info": "PO Box 271743",
        "longitude": -73.087749,
        "latitude": 41.6032207
    }, {
        "info": "P.O. Box 269",
        "longitude": -86.7818523,
        "latitude": 34.0667074
    }]
}


let array = v.locations
let value = [];
let result = array.reduce( function( sample, data){
  sample = [];
 sample.push(data.info)
  sample.push(data.longitude)
  sample.push(data.latitude)
  value.push(sample);
  return sample
},[] )

console.log("Final Value:",value)
```